# in django ,how to sum a int field and two float field in jsonb using postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, jsonb

I have a model like this:

```
class Priority(models.Model):
    base = models.FloatField(default=0)
    job = models.JSONField()
    users = models.JSONField()
```

and both `job` and `users` are similar.

like job =  {'a':1,'b':2}, user = {'c':3,'d':4}

I want to get the sum ( base + job__a  + users__c)

how can I write the filter statement,

and raw sql is fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accomplish this (updated):

```
    queryset = Priority.objects.annotate(
        a=Coalesce(
            Cast(KeyTextTransform('a', 'job'), output_field=FloatField()),
            Cast(V(0.0), output_field=FloatField())
        ),
        c=Cast(KeyTextTransform('c', 'users'), output_field=FloatField()),
    ).annotate(
        sum=Sum(
            F('base') + F('a') + F('c'), output_field=FloatField() 
        )
    )

    for item in queryset:
        print(item.sum)
```

Comment: Thanks ,if the key(`a`) is not in the json Field(job), and  I want to give a default value (0.0.),how to handle this ?

Comment: You can use F('a')